# Not getting the event from dumb component

Tags: angular, typescript

I can't getting the event from dumb component. I thought that it was working but is not binding the event to smart component. The output its ok but when i  change the event's value doesn't work and there is no displaying error.

// planet-data.component.html ( Smart component )

```
<div class="main">
    <app-loading *ngIf="loading"></app-loading>
    <app-planet-view [pics]="pics" class="fixed" (selected)="onSelect($event)"></app-planet-view>
</div>
```

// planet-data.component.ts

```
onSelect(event: Cam) {
    if (event.name === 'CHEMCAM') {
      this.loading = true;
      this.getCamType();
    } else {
      this.loading = true;
      event.name === 'NAVCAM' ? this.getCamType('spirit', 'navcam') : this.getCamType('opportunity', 'fhaz');
    }
  }
```

// dropdown-menu.component.html ( Dumb component )

```
<p-dropdown [options]="cameras" [(ngModel)]="selectedCam" placeholder="Select a Cam" optionLabel="name"
            (ngModelChange)="getDisplayCam($event)">
</p-dropdown>
```

// dropdown-menu.component.ts

```
getDisplayCam(event: Cam) {
    this.selected.emit(event);
  }
```

// planet-view.component.html ( Another Dumb component )

```
<div *ngIf="pics">
  <div *ngFor="let pic of pics.photos">
    <div class="card" style="width: 16rem;">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="{{pic.img_src}}" alt="Card image cap">
      <p>{{pic.earth_date | date}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h4>{{title}}</h4>
  <app-dropdown-menu></app-dropdown-menu>
</div>
```

Comment: please share a stackblitz url for the scenario. it will help and others can get a better understanding of the code.

Comment: Thanks but i got an issue with stackblitz, neither of the questions from stackoverflow solve that problem. So im on it. Then i will share my project, i just have it in github. Dont really know if im using the output in the correct nested component and i tried a lot of ways

Comment: Here it is my app in spite of the fact that it doesn't work in Stackblitz ( It works locally , and i tried even the posted questions about it from stackoverflow ) https://stackblitz.com/github/NachoBFL/ScientificApp

Comment: added answer please check once. Code is available in https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-vrask4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fshared%2Fcomponents%2Fplanet-view%2Fplanet-view.component.ts.

Comment: Well, seems like i got the same error in stackblitz over and over. Thanks anyway it worked locally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not emiting `selected` event in `PlanetViewComponent`. The actual `selected` event is got raised from `DropdownMenuComponent`. If you will not emit `selected` event from `PlanetViewComponent` then you can't listen to it in `PlanetDataComponent`.

Code of `planet-view.component.html` .

```
<div *ngIf="pics">
  <div *ngFor="let pic of pics.photos">
    <div class="card" style="width: 16rem;">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="{{pic.img_src}}" alt="Card image cap" routerLink="/detail">
      <p>{{pic.earth_date | date}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Added catching (selected) event -->
  <app-dropdown-menu (selected)="selected.emit($event)"></app-dropdown-menu>
</div>
```

Code of `planet-view.component.ts` is below.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-planet-view',
  templateUrl: './planet-view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./planet-view.component.sass']
})
export class PlanetViewComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() pics: Photo;

  // Added @Output() event
  @Output() selected = new EventEmitter<Cam>();
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Comment: I could note that and another thing that it would work is inside planet-data.component.html put the nest component <app-dropdown-menu> So the code is : `<app-dropdown-menu class="align" (selected)="onSelect($event)"></app-dropdown-menu>
<div class="main">
    <app-loading *ngIf="loading"></app-loading>
    <app-planet-view class="fixed" [pics]="pics"></app-planet-view>
</div>` . Thanks for your time